# iOS Objective-C Turn off Proximity Monitoring while VoiceOver is active

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, voiceover, proximitysensor

I would like to disable Proximity Monitoring, so that screen remains always ON, not matter how close something is to the sensor.

I tried it by using:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice.proximityMonitoringEnabled = NO;
```

Normally it is working as expected, however if I turn on VoiceOver, screen begins to black out if proximity sensor is covered.

FYI: I am making Video Call app (using CallKit) for people with low vision, and what they experience is that if they lean too close to the screen during a call, screen blacks out if VoiceOver is on.

I tried installing an NSTimer to set proximityMonitoringEnabled to NO every second (as a poor workaround), also tried setting it YES and then NO. It remains on NO, but screen still blacks out.

Comment: Did you figure out any solution to this issue? I am experiencing the same problem as you do, and have the same experience with the proposed solutions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately no, there is still no solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

> In VoIP apps using Apple CallKit (like yours), you can enable and disable proximity monitoring during the call using `AVAudioSession()` class. It's a known feature when a proximity sensor is triggered and a screen is dimmed while approaching user's face.
>
> By default (if you're not using CallKit) `proximityMonitoringEnabled` instance property is `OFF`.

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isProximityMonitoringEnabled) BOOL proximityMonitoringEnabled;

// or

UIDevice.currentDevice.proximityMonitoringEnabled = NO;     // DEFAULT VALUE
```

Apple's developer documentation says:

> Enable proximity monitoring only when your application needs to be notified of changes to the proximity state. Otherwise, disable proximity monitoring. **The default value is NO**.

However, if you use CallKit module, `proximityMonitoringEnabled` is not behaving as expected. By default a proximity monitoring is enabled – your app use for that a **[AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessionmodevoicechat?language=objc)** global variable:

```
const AVAudioSessionMode AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat;       // DEFAULT VALUE
```

Here's what developer documentation says here:

> If an app uses the Voice-Processing I/O audio unit and has not set its mode to one of the chat modes (voice, video, or game), `AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat` **mode will be set implicitly**.

### Disabling proximity monitoring in CallKit :

**Hence, if you want to disable a proximity monitoring just use a [AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessionmodevideochat?language=objc) global variable**:

```
const AVAudioSessionMode AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat;
```

Both variables work along with **[AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryplayandrecord?language=objc)** global variable:

```
const AVAudioSessionCategory AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord;
```

Comment: I already use this setting, and it's still not working properly.

Comment: Could you tell me what you mean saying `still not working properly`?

Comment: I had tried this before, and it didn't fix the problem. The screen still blacks out when the user leans too close.

Comment: Sorry for being late into this question. What I think you are overlooking in your answer, Andy, is the use of voice-over. Your solution is correct as long as voice-over is not activated. If you activate voice-over, however, the screen will again go blank even if you use video chat mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the session from `AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat` to `AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat`. Then the proximity sensor should get ignored

Something like that should do:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode: AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat error:&err];
```

Comment: I already use this setting, and it's still not working properly.